# ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) fails to get created

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to create a VS 2015 ASP.Net core web app (.Net Framework) project and continue to get the errors below. I tried adding proxy info to machine.config as suggested to no avail. Can anyone help?

PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\dev\WebSites.vs\restore.dg"
log  : Restoring packages for C:\dev\WebSites\NesScansV2\project.json...
info :   GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel'
info :   ProxyAuthenticationRequired https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel' 215ms
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel''.
log  : Response status code does not indicate success: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )).
info :   GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel'
info :   ProxyAuthenticationRequired https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel' 9ms
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel''.
log  : Response status code does not indicate success: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )).
info :   GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel'
info :   ProxyAuthenticationRequired https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel' 9ms
error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel''.
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )).
error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel''.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )).

Comment: Looks like this is a bug: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2393. Maybe you could try restoring with nuget restore and/or set credentials in the NuGet.Config file - https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings

Comment: Thanks, I think it is the same problem as 2393 and since that github issue and others created from it have had no added info since May 24th, I suspect it's not getting worked or is stalled for some reason. This is the problem when Microsoft rolls free code into Visual Studio, IMO.